# How to compare id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to compare a simple code where if user click on the button, then the output will display appropriate answer but I can't seem to find any correct way to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Gender</p>
 <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Female">Female</label>
 <br>
 <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  var m = document.getElementById("male").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("female").value;
   if(x === m)
    x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
    else if(x === f)
     x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="male" value="Female"` the `id` must be changed to `female`\

Comment: You have non-unique ID in HTML, that will not work with JS. Use class

Answer (score 2):

You want something like the following:

```html
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>Gender</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">Female</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo">
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
                    var m = document.getElementById("male").checked;
                    var f = document.getElementById("female").checked;
                    if (m)
                        x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
                    else if (f)
                        x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
                }
            </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

First of all you had the id for both the inputs to male, you want the female input to be female:

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">Female</label>
```

Secondly you want to get whether the radio button is checked, not it's value:

```
 var m = document.getElementById("male").value; // returns Male in your case
 var m = document.getElementById("male").checked; // returns true or false depending on whether it's been checked
```

Then the logic needs a bit of an alteration:

```
  if (m)  // they selected male
      x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
  else if (f) // they selected female
      x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second input id is "male", change it to "female". May work

Answer (score 0):

You need use `checked` to get checked radio as

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = document.getElementById("male");
  var f = document.getElementById("female");

  if(m.checked)
        x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
    else if(f.checked)
        x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Gender</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">Female</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = document.getElementById("male");
  var f = document.getElementById("female");
  
  if(m.checked)
        x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
    else if(f.checked)
        x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute specifies a **unique** id for an HTML element.

Hint: There can never be two elements (divs, labels, etc.) with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons have a property of checked to get which button is pressed so use checked property to get the value

Hope this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Gender</p>
   <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female">Female</label>
 <br>
 <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = document.getElementById("male");
  var f = document.getElementById("female");
  
 
   if(m.checked)
    x.innerHTML = "You are male.";
    else
     x.innerHTML = "You are female.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```